# Filter days of week with two different conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to tidy my daily activity data (accelerometer data). I would like to sum and average the repeated days of my data, but only for days that have `A2.Working > 6 hours`. Another condition is that the day must have completely 24 hours to be included as a valid day. The valid day will contain these 3 variables `A1.NonWorking, A2.Working, A4.SleepWeek` and their sum will be 24 hours (eg. the data bellow the `Weekday 2` don't have 24 hours, because the accelerometer was attached on this day (Tuesday). Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- tibble(
 LbNr = c(22002,22002,22002,22002,
 22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,
 22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,22002,
 22002,22002,22002,22002),
 Type = c("A2.Working","A1.NonWorking",
"A4.SleepWeek","A4.SleepWeek","A1.NonWorking","A2.Working",
"A1.NonWorking","A1.NonWorking","A4.SleepWeek","A1.NonWorking",
"A2.Working","A1.NonWorking","A4.SleepWeek","A4.SleepWeek",
"A1.NonWorking","A2.Working","A1.NonWorking","C0.Leisure",
"C4.SleepWeekend","C0.Leisure","C0.Leisure","C4.SleepWeekend",
"C0.Leisure","C4.SleepWeekend","A4.SleepWeek","A1.NonWorking"),
Weekday = c(2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,1,1),
Time = c(9.83333,6.05,0.11667,6.83333,1.33333,
9.83333,6,0.03333,7.2,6.43333,5,5.23333,0.1,6.41667,0.96667,11.01667,
5.6,0.43333,7.9,15.66667,0.03333,7.91667,15.61667,0.43333,6.33333,0.66667))
```

I tried this code without select specific days:

```
df %>% 
group_by(LbNr, Type, Weekday) %>%
summarise_all(.,sum) %>%
group_by(LbNr, Weekday) %>%
filter(any((Time >= 6 & Type == "A2.Working") | Weekday == 6 | Weekday == 7)) %>%
group_by(LbNr, Type) %>%
select(-Weekday) %>%
summarise_all(., mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But, when I run the code I get the following:

```
LbNr   Type             Time
  <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
1 22002 A1.NonWorking    6.65
2 22002 A2.Working      10.2 
3 22002 A4.SleepWeek     4.46
4 22002 C0.Leisure      15.9 
5 22002 C4.SleepWeekend  8.12
```

If I sum the workday (6.65 + 10.20 + 4.46 = 21.31) it gives me the wrong result because it sums the `Weekday 2, 3, 4, 5` of `A1.NonWorking` and `A4.SleepWeek`.

I would like a code that returns this result:

```
LbNr   Type             Time
  <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
1 22002 A1.NonWorking    6.95
2 22002 A2.Working      10.4 
3 22002 A4.SleepWeek     6.62
4 22002 C0.Leisure      15.9 
5 22002 C4.SleepWeekend  8.12
```

If I sum the workday (6.95 + 10.40 + 6.62 = 23.97, almost 24 hours), I get the correct result with the following code:

```
df %>%
group_by(LbNr, Type, Weekday) %>%
summarise_all(.,sum) %>%
filter(Weekday %in% c('3':'7')) %>% 
group_by(LbNr, Weekday) %>%
filter(any((Time >= 6 & Type == "A2.Working") | Weekday == 6 | Weekday == 7)) %>%
group_by(LbNr, Type) %>%
select(-Weekday) %>%
summarise_all(., mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I used `filter(Weekday %in% c('3':'7'))` for this volunteer because I knew that the `Weekday 2` didn't have 24 h. I would like code that returns the correct value without the need for a specific filter of days like I did. Only selecting days with 24 h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to filter using `any` Weekdays that have `Time > 6` and `Type` of `A2.Working`. This could work after grouping by `Weekday` (retain all rows for the `Weekday` if meets criteria). Also assume you would include all `Weekdays` 6 and 7 (appears to be the weekend). Is this what you had in mind?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(LbNr, Type, Weekday) %>%
  summarise_all(.,sum) %>%
  group_by(LbNr, Weekday) %>%
  filter(any((Time > 6 & Type == "A2.Working") | Weekday == 6 | Weekday == 7)) %>%
  group_by(LbNr, Type) %>%
  select(-Weekday) %>%
  summarise_all(., mean, na.rm = TRUE)


   LbNr Type             Time
  <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
1 22002 A1.NonWorking    7.27
2 22002 A2.Working      10.2 
3 22002 A4.SleepWeek     6.51
4 22002 C0.Leisure      15.9 
5 22002 C4.SleepWeekend  8.12
```

**Edit**: Based on comments, if you would like to make sure that days are included if total time is ~24hours, you can add a filter statement after grouping by `LbNr` and `Weekday` with `sum(Time)>23.9` (using a threshold close to 24 hrs).

Here's the result code, assuming again Weekday 6 and 7 will be included (whether or not 24 hrs data collected on weekend). I included the logic that made sense - though it could be simplified further (e.g., if Time < 6 hrs for A2, then criteria for 24 hrs. total would not be necessary). Hope this is closer to what you need.

```
library(dplyr)
# Edited to check for Weekdays 1:5 as having 24 hours (A1 + A2 + A4)
df %>%
  group_by(LbNr, Type, Weekday) %>%
  summarise_all(.,sum) %>%
  group_by(LbNr, Weekday) %>%
  filter(any(((Time >= 6 & Type == "A2.Working") & sum(Time) > 23.9)
              | Weekday == 6 | Weekday == 7)) %>%
  group_by(LbNr, Type) %>%
  select(-Weekday) %>%
  summarise_all(., mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi @Ben. It works very well. I'm very grateful for your helping, thanks! I was wondering if there is any way to improve this code that you have made in order to get days with complete 24 hours with this same conditions as you did. To overcome this problem I used `filter(Weekday %in% c('3':'7'))`. All of my volunteers have `Weekday 2` (Tuesday) with more than 6 hours of `A2.Working`, because I attach the accelerometer around 8 am. Sometimes because of the schedule (holidays or other stuff), some people will have day 1 as a valid day or maybe day 2 as well.

Comment: Happy to help any way i can --- just to clarify, you want to add an additional criterion to check if `Weekday` is between 3 and 7? Would you want to apply the `A2.Working` and `Time>6` criteria only to `Weekday` 3:5, and automatically include weekdays of 1 and 2 as well as weekend days of 6 and 7? In addition, if you update/edit your question with an example to work off of I can edit the above answer with an additional response. Just wanted to make sure i understand completely.

Comment: Hi @Ben. Thanks in advance for your attention. I edited my post, I think now I could express it better.

Comment: @LuizBrusaca - see edited answer and let me know if this addresses what you need.

Comment: Hi @Ben. Thanks, it works very well. I'm grateful for your helping.